# Summation involving addition modulo $2$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, finite-fields

I'm working on a problem that I was able to reduce to the following:

> Let $S$ be an $m$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{Z}_2^n$ and $\mathrm{w}\in \{0,1\}^n$. Prove that $$\sum_{\mathrm{s}\in S} (-1)^{\mathrm{s}\cdot \mathrm{w}} = 0 \Leftrightarrow \mathrm{w} \not\in S^{\perp}$$
> where $\mathrm{s}\cdot\mathrm{w}=\mathrm{s_1}\mathrm{w_1}\oplus \dots \oplus \mathrm{s_n}\mathrm{w_n}$ and $\oplus$ denotes addition modulo $2$.

Now I approached the problem as follows: The forward implication is trivial. For the reverse, let $\{\mathrm{s_1},\dots \mathrm{s_m}\}$ be an orthonormal basis of $S$ and write $\mathrm{w}=\mathrm{s_w}\oplus\mathrm{s_w}' \in S \oplus S^\perp$ (direct sum). In that case, the sum comes out to
$$\sum_{\mathrm{s}\in S} (-1)^{\mathrm{s}\cdot \mathrm{s_w}}$$
and $\mathrm{s_w}\neq\mathbf{0}$. If $\mathrm{s_w}=\bigoplus \lambda_i \mathrm{s_i}$ and $\mathrm{s}=\bigoplus\kappa_i \mathrm{s_i}$ where $\lambda_i, \kappa_i \in \mathbb{Z}_2$ then
$$\mathrm{s}\cdot \mathrm{s_z}=\bigoplus_{i=1}^m \lambda_i\bigoplus_{j\neq i}\kappa_i$$

My idea from here is to show that for exactly half of the $2^m$ possible assignments for the values of $\kappa_i$ the above sum vanishes therefore proving the original statement.

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: I'm a bit unsure what you mean by (-1)^{sw}, or rather, your definition right underneath. Am I correct in interpreting it as s_1w_1 + ... + s_nw_n working modulo 2 or do you actually mean a direct sum of vectors, with each component being modulo 2? If it's the latter, what definition of a scalar to the power of a vector are you working with?

Comment: @Peatherfed You are correct to interpret it as addition modulo $2$. Perhaps my notation is a bit confusing but the only time I interpret $\oplus$ as a direct sum is when I am considering the direct sum of $S$ and $S^\perp$ as subspaces. Everywhere else the symbol is equivalent to $a_1b_1+\dots+a_nb_n \pmod{2}$.

Comment: Note: there's no reason that an 'orthonormal basis' should exist for $S$.  Similarly you may do $S+S^\perp$ but there's no reason to think this is a direct sum.

Comment: @user8675309 Is this because we are working over $\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: @user8675309 There is very much a reason to think that an orthonormal basis should exist for S, considering the question is marked as finite fields.

Comment: my read: OP is working on $V=\mathbb F_2^n$ using the dot product as a bilinear form -- this means that there are many self orthogonal vectors.

Comment: @user8675309 I am considering $\mathbb{Z}_2^n$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ so you are right. For example, $(1,0,0)$ is self-orthogonal (for $n=3$) so I shouldn't have assumed that an orthonormal basis exists nor that we can write that direct sum. Perhaps there is another combinatorial argument?

Comment: If $w\notin S^\perp$ there exists at least one $z_0\in S$ such that $z_0\cdot w\neq0$. Hence $z_0\cdot w=1$. Call that sum $M$. Then $z+z_0$ ranges over $S$ as $z$ does, so
$$M=\sum_{z\in S}(-1)^{z\cdot w}=\sum_{z\in S}(-1)^{(z+z_0)\cdot w}=(-1)^{z_0\cdot w}\sum_{z\in S}(-1)^{z\cdot w}=-M.$$ Therefore $M=0$.

Comment: The above is the standard proof. Sometimes called *orthogonality of characters* (makes more sense in some other contexts) or *the sum of the values of a non-trivial character vanishes*.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $w\not\in S^\perp$. We show that $\sum_{s\in S} (-1)^{s\cdot w} = 0$ by finding for every $s \in S$ such that $s \cdot w = 1$ an $r\in S$ such that $r\cdot w = 0$. Thus by pairing the sum is zero. Suppose then that $s\cdot w = 1$ for some $s \in S$. Since $w\not\in S^\perp$ there exists a $v\in S$ such that $v\cdot w = 1$. Let $r = s + v$. Then $r\cdot w = (s+v)\cdot w = s\cdot v + v\cdot w = 1 + 1 \equiv 0$.

Third time's the charm, right? ;)

Answer (score 0):

So I think I figured it out. Let $\{s_1,\cdots,s_m\}$ be a basis of $S$ and also let $s = a_1 s_1 \oplus a_2 s_2 \oplus \dots \oplus a_m s_m$. Since $w\not\in S^\perp$ we have
$$s\cdot w = a_1 (s_1\cdot w) \oplus \dots \oplus a_m(s_m\cdot w)$$
with not all $s_i \cdot w$ being zero.

Now partition the $s_i$'s in two sets $I_0$ and $I_1$ depending on whether $s_i \cdot w$ equals zero or one. Now notice that if the size of $I_1$ is odd then an assignment of $a_i$'s will give $s\cdot w = 1$ if and only if its complement will give $0$. If the size of $I_1$ is even then every assignment of $a_i$'s will give the same value as its complement and exactly half of them will give $0$ (those who select an even number of elements from $I_1$) and the rest will give $1$. In any case, the number of $+1$ terms in our summation will be equal to the number of $-1$ terms. Turns out not much linear algebra was needed!